# Using Observable map operator to flatted an array

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

So let's say I have a function that returns an `Observable` of the object `ObjectReturned` below:

```js
interface ObjectReturned {
  id: string,
    information: info[],
    anotherObj: AnotherObj[]
}

interface AnotherObj {
  information: info[]
}

interface info {
  name: string
}
```

Given that `ObjectReturned.info[]` and `AnotherObj.info[]` both **always contain only one element each**, how can I use the `map` operator of `Observable` to "flatten" the `info` array above so that I can access the returned result (`Observable<ObjectReturned>`) using `objectReturned.name` and `objectReturned.anotherObj.name` directly?

Comment: observable has nothing to do with that. Just use map and then flatten it yourself. ``const [firstAndOnlyValue] = yourArray``; and then use firstAndOnlyValue how you want

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, sorry, I still want to return an observable of `ObjectReturned`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
objectReturned.map( obj => Object.assign(obj, {name: information[0].name});
```

this gives

```
{
  id: string,
  name: string,
    anotherObj: AnotherObj[]
}
```

You can further apply the same to `anotherObj` too. let me know if this is what you are looking for.